# What are the steps in trying to obtain $x(t)$? how does integration come in?

Tags: calculus

A force of mass $m=2$, is given by $F=9e^{-3t}$. If the particle has velocity $V=1$ and position $x=\frac{1}{3}$ at $t=0$, obtain $x(t)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$a=\frac{F}m$$
$$a(t)=\frac92e^{-3t}$$
$$v(t)=\int_0^t \frac92e^{-3t}\,dt + v_0=-\frac32e^{-3t}+\frac32+1$$
$$x(t)=\int_0^t (-\frac32e^{-3t}+\frac52)\,dt + x_0=\frac12e^{-3t}+\frac52t-\frac12+1/3$$

Comment: but @kamil09875, haven't you made a mistake with the signs of the constants when t=0? why are you changing signs?